# Back up iChat logs to Gmail?

Tags: email, ichat, archive

Is it possible to automatically back up iChats to Gmail? There used to be a program called Chatalog but it's discontinued now.

---

Some details about [Chatalog](http://chatalog.en.softonic.com/mac):

> Chatalog is a powerful app for seamlessly storing your iChats directly in your email program, exactly where all of your other online correspondence is kept, and where it is easy to group and search. What's more, Chatalog compiles lists of the links and images sent via iChat and builds them into convenient web pages for you to browse.
>
> Features:
>
> - Find important files and weblinks instantly
> - Browse through all the images you have sent or received
> - Keep all your vital communications in a single place
> - Organize your iChats the same way you organize your email (Set up Rules, Folders, etc)

Comment: How do you mean "back up to Gmail"? To you want them automatically emailed to someone?

Comment: @CajunLuke So basically every time somebody chats with me in iChat, the chat session is saved in a Gmail folder as a message thread. Gmail already does this when you chat using Google Talk... the message archive is saved in the Gmail chat folder.